# Having problem passing date and time variables to another php page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two forms that pass the same date and time variables to another PHP page.  FORM 1 works perfectly, but FORM 2 DOES NOT.  They are passing the same hidden name and id variables.  I don't think any of my styling could cause this, but could be wrong.  Can someone please help me see the ovious.  Thanks

```
<script>
function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, positionError );
}
}

function showPosition(position) {
document.getElementById("getlat").value = position.coords.latitude;
document.getElementById("getlon").value = position.coords.longitude;

lon=document.getElementById("getlon").value;
lat=document.getElementById("getlat").value;

}

function positionError(error) {
if(error.PERMISSION_DENIED) alert("Please accept geolocation")
hideLoadingDiv()
showError('Geolocation is not enabled. Please enable to use this feature')
}

</script>

<script>

function ShowLocalDate()
{
var dNow = new Date();
var local_year1= dNow.getFullYear();
var local_month1= dNow.getMonth()+1;
var local_day1= dNow.getDate();
var local_hour1= dNow.getHours();
var local_minutes1= dNow.getMinutes();
var local_seconds1= dNow.getSeconds();

document.getElementById("local_year").value = local_year1;
document.getElementById("local_month").value = local_month1;
document.getElementById("local_day").value = local_day1;
document.getElementById("local_hour").value = local_hour1;
document.getElementById("local_minutes").value = local_minutes1;
document.getElementById("local_seconds").value = local_seconds1;
}
<script>
```

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-5" style="background-color:pink1;text-align:right">
```

The FORM below works!

```
<!--  FORM 1 -->
<form action="shop_load.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="getlon">    
<input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="getlat"> 
<input type="hidden" id="local_year" name="local_year" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_month" name="local_month" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_day" name="local_day" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_hour" name="local_hour" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_minutes" name="local_minutes" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_seconds" name="local_seconds" />

<button  style="float:right;background-color:#48a0dc;
text-align:center" type="submit" class="btn " >
<span style="font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
font-weight: 100;font-size:22px;float:right;
color:white;text-align:center;border-radius:7px;padding-right:5px;padding-left:5px">
Allow GPS
</span>
</button>
</form>
</div> 

<div class="col-1" style="color:white;text-align:center;font-size:20px;background-color:grey1">
OR&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

The FORM below DOES NOT work!

```
<div class="col-5" style="background-color:lime1;color:white;text-align:left">
<form action="shop_load.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="local_year" name="local_year" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_month" name="local_month" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_day" name="local_day" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_hour" name="local_hour" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_minutes" name="local_minutes" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_seconds" name="local_seconds" />
<input focus style="font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; 
font-weight: 100;font-size:22px;background-color:#48a0dc;float:left;text-align:center;border-radius:5px;
width:100px;border:none;color:white;margin-left:30px"  class="btn fas" name="zip" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Zipcode"  />
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-5 animated pulse infinite slower" style="background-color:pink1;text-align:right">
<br>
<a href="#c1" class="" style="margin-left:15px;color:white;font-size:16px;font-style:italic">Gps info-why?</a>
</div>

<div class="col-1" style="background-color:grey1;text-align:center">
</div>

<button  style="float:right;background-color:#48a0dc;
text-align:center" type="submit" class="btn " >
<i class="fas fa-search"></i>"
</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Then my shop_load.php contains the following code to load variables

```
<?php
$local_year = isset($_REQUEST['local_year']) ? $_REQUEST['local_year'] : "";
echo 'local_year= ' . $local_year;

$local_month = isset($_REQUEST['local_month']) ? $_REQUEST['local_month'] : "";
echo 'local_month= ' . $local_month;

$local_day = isset($_REQUEST['local_day']) ? $_REQUEST['local_day'] : "";
echo 'local_day= ' . $local_day;

$local_hour = isset($_REQUEST['local_hour']) ? $_REQUEST['local_hour'] : "";
echo 'local_hour= ' . $local_hour;

$local_minutes = isset($_REQUEST['local_minutes']) ? $_REQUEST['local_minutes'] : "";
echo 'local_minutes= ' . $local_minutes;

$local_seconds = isset($_REQUEST['local_seconds']) ? $_REQUEST['local_seconds'] : "";
echo 'local_seconds= ' . $local_seconds;
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with your second form. How do you know it doesn't pass the value? Did you call the `ShowLocalDate()` on second form?

Comment: What have you investigated? Just saying it "DOES NOT work" implies you haven't done anything. Normally you would first check for obvious bugs, then you would check which values are submitted and you check what values are received. If, after that, you still don't understand why it doesn't work, you can ask a question here, and you would report the result of your investigation and tell us why, given that, you don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: I  was just wondering if there was something I was overlooking.  As far as testing is concerned, I did.  FORM 1 sends and displays the variables to my PHP page and  Form 2 does not.  This is why I asked the question, I don't know what else to test as I have tried probable 20 other ways, I even tried using a different data time function

Comment: and no I do not call ShowLocalDate() on the second page, I shouldn't have to

Comment: Are both forms on same page?

Comment: yes both forms are on the same page

Comment: Ok try changing the id and name of all inputs in the 2nd form, for example `<input type="hidden" id="local_year1" name="local_year1" />`  and also in the php file. The thing is the php file can be confused there are 2 inputs with same name so it always gets the first one.

Comment: I would recommend to do a shop_load1.php with same code but different names(same as in 2nd form{local_year1...})

Comment: Changing the ID and Name did the trick, thanks Himas.

Answer (score 0):

I created a second set of ID variables and called those ID vales in form 2 and it works perfectly.  The working code is below.

```
<script>
function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, positionError );
}
}

function showPosition(position) {
document.getElementById("getlat").value = position.coords.latitude;
document.getElementById("getlon").value = position.coords.longitude;

lon=document.getElementById("getlon").value;
lat=document.getElementById("getlat").value;

}

function positionError(error) {
if(error.PERMISSION_DENIED) alert("Please accept geolocation")
hideLoadingDiv()
showError('Geolocation is not enabled. Please enable to use this feature')
}

</script>

<script>

function ShowLocalDate()
{
var dNow = new Date();
var local_year1= dNow.getFullYear();
var local_month1= dNow.getMonth()+1;
var local_day1= dNow.getDate();
var local_hour1= dNow.getHours();
var local_minutes1= dNow.getMinutes();
var local_seconds1= dNow.getSeconds();

document.getElementById("local_year").value = local_year1;
document.getElementById("local_month").value = local_month1;
document.getElementById("local_day").value = local_day1;
document.getElementById("local_hour").value = local_hour1;
document.getElementById("local_minutes").value = local_minutes1;
document.getElementById("local_seconds").value = local_seconds1;

document.getElementById("local_year2").value = local_year1;
document.getElementById("local_month2").value = local_month1;
document.getElementById("local_day2").value = local_day1;
document.getElementById("local_hour2").value = local_hour1;
document.getElementById("local_minutes2").value = local_minutes1;
document.getElementById("local_seconds2").value = local_seconds1;

}

<script>


<div class="caption">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-5" style="background-color:pink1;text-align:right">


<!--  FORM 1 -->
<form action="shop_load.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="getlon">    
<input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="getlat"> 
<input type="hidden" id="local_year" name="local_year" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_month" name="local_month" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_day" name="local_day" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_hour" name="local_hour" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_minutes" name="local_minutes" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_seconds" name="local_seconds" />

<button  style="float:right;background-color:#48a0dc;
text-align:center" type="submit" class="btn " >
<span style="font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
font-weight: 100;font-size:22px;float:right;
color:white;text-align:center;border-radius:7px;padding-right:5px;padding-left:5px">
Allow GPS
</span>
</button>
</form>
</div> 

<div class="col-1" style="color:white;text-align:center;font-size:20px;background-color:grey1">
OR&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>

<!--  FORM 2  -->

<div class="col-5" style="background-color:lime1;color:white;text-align:left">
<form action="shop_load.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="local_year2" name="local_year" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_month2" name="local_month" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_day2" name="local_day" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_hour2" name="local_hour" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_minutes2" name="local_minutes" />
<input type="hidden" id="local_seconds2" name="local_seconds" />
<input focus style="font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; 
font-weight: 100;font-size:22px;background-color:#48a0dc;float:left;text-align:center;border-radius:5px;
width:100px;border:none;color:white;margin-left:30px"  class="btn fas" name="zip" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Zipcode"  />
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-5 animated pulse infinite slower" style="background-color:pink1;text-align:right">
<br>
<a href="#c1" class="" style="margin-left:15px;color:white;font-size:16px;font-style:italic">Gps info-why?</a>
</div>

<div class="col-1" style="background-color:grey1;text-align:center">
</div>

<button  style="float:right;background-color:#48a0dc;
text-align:center" type="submit" class="btn " >
<i class="fas fa-search"></i>"
</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Then my shop_load.php contains the following code to load variables

```
<?php
$local_year = isset($_REQUEST['local_year']) ? $_REQUEST['local_year'] : "";
echo 'local_year= ' . $local_year;

$local_month = isset($_REQUEST['local_month']) ? $_REQUEST['local_month'] : "";
echo 'local_month= ' . $local_month;

$local_day = isset($_REQUEST['local_day']) ? $_REQUEST['local_day'] : "";
echo 'local_day= ' . $local_day;

$local_hour = isset($_REQUEST['local_hour']) ? $_REQUEST['local_hour'] : "";
echo 'local_hour= ' . $local_hour;

$local_minutes = isset($_REQUEST['local_minutes']) ? $_REQUEST['local_minutes'] : "";
echo 'local_minutes= ' . $local_minutes;

$local_seconds = isset($_REQUEST['local_seconds']) ? $_REQUEST['local_seconds'] : "";
echo 'local_seconds= ' . $local_seconds;
```